# Flutter test vs flutter run

Tags: flutter, testing

I have a class that uses the `geolocator` package to get a users location. I have created a mock of the geolocator package and called `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` at the beginning of the `main()` function of the test file.

If I run `flutter run path/to/test/file` in the terminal, all tests in that file pass. If I do `flutter test` or `flutter test path/to/test/file` then a few of the test fail, throwing a `MissingPluginException` for one of the methods in the `geolocator` class.

This leads me to believe that `flutter run` and `flutter test` do two slightly different things. What is the difference, and what can I do to get my tests passing with `flutter test`?